# Unable to link .so file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, javacv, tbb, .so

I'm compiling javacv with Android and I get a runtime error

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "../../lib/libtbb.so" not found
```

I have added **libtbb.so** in the **app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi**
But still I get the error, I have even tried other methods.

Could you please help?

Comment: armeabi is for ARMv5. That is for very, very old devices. You probably want armeabi-v7a.

Comment: @StenSoft: I still get the same error
Here is my app.gradle file with the dependencies

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.so'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile project(':opencv-java')
    compile files('libs/javacpp.jar')
    compile files('libs/javacv.jar')
}

Comment: Did you find any solution?